# Is there any way to download a file in at constant speed?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, download, request

I am trying to write a script in python or nodejs which can download a file, image or video at constant speed, lets say average download rate of my connection is 10 mbs/s but I want to dedicate 3 mbs/s speed to that script and it must download the media at that constant speed.

Comment: This is too broad of a question. Mu gut tells me you can't do this because you don't control the pipe between your connection and where the file is stored. The network that makes the internet is just too broad of an area to be able to have that kind of control. But again, this is just too broad of a question.

Comment: I just want do download a pdf file, and I want to limit the download speed, for example I don`t want speed to exceed 100kbps for that particular download.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm sure there is a way to do it because some BitTorrent clients have a speed cap. But I don't know how you would implement it off the top of my head.